# Extract line from text file based on leading characters of each line

Tags: bash, batch-file

I have a very large data dump that I need to manipulate. Basically, I receive a text file that has data from multiple tables in it.  The first two characters of each line will tell me what table this is from. I need to read each of these lines and then extract them into a TEXT file... It would append each line to the text file. Each table should have it's own text file.

For example, lets say the data file looks like this...

```
HDxxxxxxxxxxxxx
HDyyyyyyyyyyyyy
ENxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ENyyyyyyyyyyyyy
HSyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

What I would need is the first two lines to be in a text file named HD_out.txt, the 3rd and 4th lines in one named EN_out.txt, and the last one in a file named HS_out.txt.

Does anyone know how could this be done with either a simple batch file or UNIX shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to split file based on first 2 characters:

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 99999' '{print $2 > $1"_out.txt"}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```
while read -r line; do 
    echo "${line:2}" >> "${line:0:2}_out.txt"
done < inputFile
```

`${var:startposition:length}` is a `bash` string function to capture sub-strings. This would cause your inputfile to be split based on the first two chars. If you **want** to include the table prefix, just use `echo "$line" >> "${line:0:2}_out.txt"` instead of what is shown above.

**Demo:**

```
$ ls
file
```

```
$ cat file
HDxxxxxxxxxxxxx
HDyyyyyyyyyyyyy
ENxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ENyyyyyyyyyyyyy
HSyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

```
$ while read -r line; do echo "${line:2}" >> "${line:0:2}_out.txt"; done < file
```

```
$ ls
EN_out.txt  file  HD_out.txt  HS_out.txt
```

```
$ head *.txt
==> EN_out.txt <==
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyy

==> HD_out.txt <==
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyy

==> HS_out.txt <==
yyyyyyyyyyyyy
```